# Perfmon Configuration or Alert Utility for CPU usage over period of time.

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, perfmon, alerts

I'm familiar with general perfmon configuration. However, is there a way to alert when the CPU goes to say 95%, but only if it stays there for over X minutes?

If not, does anyone know a free/cheap solution? I need to be able to fire off a script when this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a task in Task Scheduler to run your script, then create a new alert in Perfmon and specify your task as the alert action.  Microsoft documents the process [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722414.aspx).

However I don't believe this will currently be stateful and track it for x amount of time.  SCOM is often used for that, but is not free/cheap.